# Making SparseArray<> Included ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sparse-array

i need to make a List of ArrayList , my idea was it:

```
 Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>> SentReportMap=new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();
```

that tell :

```
 Use new SparseArray<ArrayList<String>>(...) instead for better performance
```

so , i try this :

```
 SparseArray<String> SentReportMap = new SparseArray<String>();

 ArrayList<String> items=new ArrayList<String>();

 items.add(array.getProperty("To").toString());
 items.add(array.getProperty("Date").toString());

 SentReportMap.put(1, items);
```

but for fill this array with data , return this error :

```
The method put(int, String) in the type SparseArray<String> is not applicable for the arguments (int, ArrayList<String>)
```

Or

```
The method put(int, String) in the type SparseArray<String> is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<String>, int)
```

where is wrong and what is better solution for making a arraylist of arrays!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaration of SentReportMap is wrong, it should be:

```
SparseArray<ArrayList<String>> SentReportMap = new SparseArray<ArrayList<String>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 SparseArray<String> SentReportMap = new SparseArray<String>();
```

to

```
SparseArray<ArrayList<String>> SentReportMap = new SparseArray<ArrayList<String>>();
```

SparseArray is better solution because :

`SparseArrays map integers to Objects. Unlike a normal array of Objects, there can be gaps in the indices. It is intended to be more memory efficient than using a HashMap to map Integers to Objects, both because it avoids auto-boxing keys and its data structure doesn't rely on an extra entry object for each mapping.`

check this link for more information.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html